# Android - Open Protocol (Bonjour) like on iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, bonjour, zeroconf

in the iOS world data can be exchanged between applications through the use of Open Protocol. For example if I have an e-mail with a pdf attachment I can open it into PDFExpert, even if the apps runs on a SandBox and they don't have share file system.

In case of Android I noticed that such a procedure is different, for example I can save a document into the file system let's say /mnt/Apps_Name and then I can reopen that document in an other apps.

Is there a way to have the user to experience data/documents exchanging between apps like in the iOS World? Do you have any example? Some references to the official documentation? Do they need some Bonjour or Zero Conf implementation?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the Intent approach is what you are looking for. By setting an action to an Intent, let's say for example, ACTION_VIEW, you set the corresponding data in the Intent (i.e. a pdf file), and the system determines which apps are capable of showing that information. If more than one app are capable, usually a dialog promps to let the user decide the app.

View PDF example:

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Intents feature is one of my favourites in Android Development. See for example how easy is to share any file/text/image/... without the pain of implementing any Oauth/Oauth2....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String toShare = "This is the text to share";
// You can add extras
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");

// Start intent with choose prompt
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.1 adds [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) which should be exactly what you want — seems to actually be implemented on top of Bonjour [under the hood](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html).